# Write a predicate same_name(Person1,Person2) that returns true if Person 1 and Person 2 have same family name

Tags: prolog

```
parent(albert, jim).
parent(albert, peter).
parent(jim, brian).
parent(john, darren).
parent(peter, lee).
parent(peter, sandra).
parent(peter, james).
parent(peter, kate).
parent(peter, kyle).
parent(brian, jenny).
parent(irene, jim).
parent(irene, peter).
parent(pat, brian).
parent(pat, darren).
parent(amanda, jenny).

female(irene).
female(pat).
female(lee).
female(sandra).
female(jenny).
female(amanda).
female(kate).
male(albert).
male(jim).
male(peter).
male(brian).
male(john).
male(darren).
male(james).
male(kyle).
```

We assume that each person will have the same family name as their father, but that married women retain their original birth name.

Example :

```
?- same_name(pat, brian).
false.

?- same_name(jenny, jim).
true
```

I wrote conditions to check if they have same father or one of them is grandfather :

```
check_grandfather(A,B) :-
 parent(A,X),
 parent(X,B).

check_siblings(A,b) :-
 parent(X,A),
 parent(X,B),
 A \== B.
```

but I can not understand how can I use conditions to check same_name.
I am thinking something like,

```
same_name(P1,P2) :-
 check_siblings(P1,P2),
 check_grandfather(P1,P2).
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I am very new to prolog so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the family name in your facts?

Comment: @GuyCoder there isn't. We have to figure out by the assumption "each person will have the same family name as their father, but that married women retain their original birth name." and return true or false if the two people share the family name. So I wrote conditions for checking grandfather and siblings to check the family name

Comment: Ahh! I see now.

Comment: @GuyCoder where do you think i am going wrong ?

Comment: Is `pat` married to both `john` and `jim` ? As I noted the only way to tell if a couple is married is to look for parents with common children. So `Darren` has parents `parent(john, darren).` and `parent(pat, darren).` and `brain` has parents `parent(jim, brian).` and `parent(pat, brian).` How is the family name of `pat` determined?